# Using EasyMock to mock an interface that accepts arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I have a class `MyClass` that contains a constructor that calls an interface `MyInterface`. `MyInterface` contains a method `validator` that accepts an `Int` and a `String`.

I need to use EasyMock to mock a return `Boolean` value from `MyInterface.validator` within a JUnit test.

I have made several attempts at this put I only get Java Exceptions when I try to call `MyInterface.validator` from `MyClass`.

```
public class MyClass {

public MyInterface myInterface;
public int test;

public MyClass (int INT, String STRING, MyInterface myInterface) {

    this.myInterface = myInterface;
    this.test = INT;
    myInterface.validator(INT, STRING);

}
}
```

---

```
public interface MyInterface {
public Boolean validator(int INT, String STRING);
}
```

---

```
public class MyClassTest {
MyInterface mockMyInterface;
MyClass myClass;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMyInterface = createMock(MyInterface.class);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    myClass = new MyClass(10, "Test", mockMyInterface);
    expect(mockMyInterface.validator(10, "Test")).andStubReturn(true);
    replay(mockMyInterface);
    assertEquals(myClass.test, 10);
    verify(mockMyInterface);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure mock expectations before using it. Your constructor invoke the mock, so you should configure it before creating an instance of MyClass.

Try this :

```
public class MyClassTest {
  MyInterface mockMyInterface;
  MyClass myClass;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
      mockMyInterface = createMock(MyInterface.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    expect(mockMyInterface.validator(10, "Test")).andStubReturn(true);
    replay(mockMyInterface);

    myClass = new MyClass(10, "Test", mockMyInterface);    

    assertEquals(myClass.test, 10);
    verify(mockMyInterface);
  }
}
```